# Change order of text and image on small screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have on page text and image under that text (multiple blocks). 
**Sample** : [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pycg0pcn/1/)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/mrmen/images/5/52/Small.gif/revision/latest?cb=20100731114437" class="img-responsive"/>
        <br/>
        <h4>Test Text</h4>
    </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
                         <img src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/mrmen/images/5/52/Small.gif/revision/latest?cb=20100731114437" class="img-responsive"/>
        <br/>
        <h4>Test Text</h4>
         </div>
</div>
```

But on small screens text which is under image can be recognized by user as text for next image, which is wrong.

So i want to move text above the image on small screens.

Ideas that i have currently - add duplicate of existing text and add bootstrap classes hidden/visible to them. And switch text in order to size of screen.

But i hope there is more ellegant solution without adding same text again but in different possition

Comment: try this: https://scotch.io/tutorials/reorder-css-columns-using-bootstrap

Comment: you mean when you're in small screen the text for the image will be display above the image?

Comment: In case someone is facing this problem with Wordpress + Elementor (Google brought me here), there is an easy solution: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GysPzwQMU1g

Answer (score 0):

Try this..I edited your code

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
         <h4>Test Text</h4>
        <img src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/mrmen/images/5/52/Small.gif/revision/latest?cb=20100731114437" class="img-responsive"/>
         <h4>Test Text</h4>
        <br/>

    </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
                         <img src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/mrmen/images/5/52/Small.gif/revision/latest?cb=20100731114437" class="img-responsive"/>
        <br/>

         </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tell exactly what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries and display: flex property and order the elements.

CSS

```
@media (max-width:768px) {
.row .col-md-6 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  order: 2;
}

h4 {
  order: 1;
 }
}
```